# Problem trying to get values from my API Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to get the values from my API but I can't show them in `ion-list`.

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

As you can see in the image I got the data from my API but I can show them in `ion-list`.

The HTML is this

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of (results | async)">

  <ion-label text-wrap>{{item.nombreProducto}}</ion-label>
  <ion-button color="light"><img src="../../assets/icon/binoculars.png" alt="" (click)="presentarModal()" item-end></ion-button>
  <ion-button color="light"><img src="../../assets/icon/cart.png" alt="" (click)="addCart()" item-end></ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

I've created a service that has a method called `getAll`

```
   getAll(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}`).pipe(
      map(results=>{
        console.log('Data', results);
        return results['Data'];
      })
    );
  }
```

And in my home.page.ts the `getAll` method contains this

```
getAll(){
  this.results = this.productService.getAll();
}
```

Comment: Is the response data array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a key in the array which does not exist. Your `results` is the data you are looking for that you want to return. Update your method to the following:

```
getAll(): Observable<any>{
return this.http.get(`${this.url}`).pipe(
  map(results=>{
    console.log('Data', results);
    return results;
  })
);
```

Comment: One more question, how should be the method to search? because Im using one like getAll but doesn't woirk

Comment: @RoberthTorres If `results` is an array you can use the `.filter` method on the array to search for specific item(s) you can then loop through the results of the filter method and identify the items you are looking for.

Comment: is an object and I was thinking in something like this but doesn't work
`searchData(codigo: number): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${codigo}`).pipe(
        map(results => {
          console.log('Data', results);
          return results;
        })
      );
    }`

Answer (score 0):

With angular versions 4.x and higher the syntax for the async pipe and how to reference it's values in the ngFor may be incorrect, try:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item  *ngFor="let item of results | async as item">

  <ion-label text-wrap>{{item.nombreProducto}}</ion-label>
  <ion-button color="light"><img src="../../assets/icon/binoculars.png" alt="" (click)="presentarModal()" item-end></ion-button>
  <ion-button color="light"><img src="../../assets/icon/cart.png" alt="" (click)="addCart()" item-end></ion-button>
</ion-item>
```

This syntax change between angular versions is better explained here:

"While in version 2 we had to fallback to subscribing to the Observable in the component class, Angular version 4 now gives us a possibility to handle such scenario by assigning the async result from the Observable to a template variable"

https://juristr.com/blog/2017/06/new-enhanced-ngIf-and-ngFor/#enumerate-ngfor-loops-using-as-and-async-pipes

Answer (score 0):

`results` is an array of objects, you are returning `results['Data']` in your rxjs `map` which does not exist. I assume your own `console.log` confused you into thinking the structure has a `Data` property.